# Is there are Maven repository to get prerelease Mapstruct 1.3 jars?

Tags: mapstruct

I have noticed that Mapstruct 1.3 will introduce [constructor injection](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/pull/1263). Is there a Maven repository containing SNAPSHOT releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapStruct SNAPSHOTs are published at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots. You can also use https://jitpack.io/ in case you want to take a specific commit from MapStruct

Comment: Do they publish the 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT documentation somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, we have not published that. However, you can look into the source ascidoc files. You can also opwn an issue for us to do that (you can contribute it if you want too as well)

Comment: No worries. Thats fair enough. I just gave it a try. Is this constructor injection already working? See my issue https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1395

Comment: Yes, it should work. You are experiencing a corner case where the mapper is not used and thus no field is added. I am currently travelling, so would be able to fix it once I am back (in few hours)